# no gradle tool in Tool windows in idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

How to make show up gradle Projects in idea.I search from View->Tool Window-> but there is only maven project. I already loaded gradle project, but I can't manage it due to not existing gradle projects.How I could make show up it or I should download it from somewhere
[image]

Comment: right-click on your `build.gradle` file in project explorer, you should have an option "import gradle project",  this will "convert" your project into a Gradle project in IDEA.

Comment: thank for you answer but there is no import gradle project

Comment: I think in older IDEA version you have to close the project and reopen it. IDEA will then ask you if you want to import the gradle file.

Comment: Try removing .idea folder, and reimporting the project from Gradle model.

Comment: yes this one works for me thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 9):

IntelliJ have certainly had trouble solving this particular problem, but as of 2018.3.6 the solution has certainly gotten better:

1. find the gradle.build file
2. right-click on it and select **Import Gradle Project**.
   no idea () why they've decided to do it this way, but it works, the Gradle tool window becomes available, and it has become a gradle project.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2
There is a disabled_plugins.txt, open it and delete the "org.gradle..." things and save it. Restart IntelliJ. It helped me, there are Gradle options in New Projects.